# Netty 4: Processing both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: http, https, netty

I'd like to process HTTP connections to port 80 and HTTPS to port 443 with shared handler.

What I do currently is creating two separate ServerBootstraps, ChannelInitializers share the instance of my handler and one of them adds SslHandler to the pipeline.

Is there a better way to do this?
If using this way, can I share EventLoopGroups to reduce thread usage (I have pretty small number of concurrent connections)? Is there something I should note when doing this with OIO/NIO/AIO, when sharing parent and child groups?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you able to share the code that you implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can share the EventLoops and probably should even do it.. The rest of what you do sounds like the way to go.